# Evaluate tree with expression inside other expression

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

For starters I would like to apologise if I am not being precise on the matter.

```
grammar Test;

@parser::header {#pragma warning disable 3021}
@lexer::header {#pragma warning disable 3021}

prog                       : expression? EOF;
expression                 : TEXT #text
                       | shift_left #shiftLeft
                       | shift_right #shiftRight
                       | upper_case #upperCase
                       | lower_case #lowerCase
                       | substring #ssubstring
                       | expression CONCANTENATE expression #concatenate
                       ;
substring : SUBSTRING OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET;
shift_left : SHIFT_LEFT OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET;
shift_right : SHIFT_RIGHT OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET;
upper_case  : UPPER OBRACKET expression CBRACKET;
lower_case : LOWER OBRACKET expression CBRACKET;

compileUnit
    :   EOF
    ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

fragment L          : ('L'|'l') ;
fragment E          : ('E'|'e') ;
fragment F          : ('F'|'f') ;
fragment T          : ('T'|'t') ;
fragment U          : ('U'|'u') ;
fragment P          : ('P'|'p') ;
fragment R          : ('R'|'r') ;
fragment O          : ('O'|'o') ;
fragment W          : ('W'|'w') ;
fragment I          : ('I'|'i') ;
fragment G          : ('G'|'g') ;
fragment H          : ('H'|'h') ;
fragment S          : ('S'|'s') ;
fragment B          : ('B'|'b') ;
fragment N          : ('N'|'n') ;

COMMA               : ',';
OBRACKET            : '(';
CBRACKET            : ')';
CONCANTENATE        : '+';

NUMBER              : [1-9] (DIGIT)*;
DIGIT               : [0-9];


SHIFT_RIGHT         : R I G H T;
UPPER               : U P P E R;
LOWER               : L O W E R;
SUBSTRING           : S U B S T R I N G;
SHIFT_LEFT          : L E F T;

TEXT                : '"' .*? '"';
WHITESPACE          : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ -> skip ;

WS
   :   ' ' -> channel(HIDDEN)
   ;
```

What I want to achive is to evaluate the tree (or in other words - to be able to actually do simple operations). The whole idea of the grammar is to perform simple operations on strings. The problem itself is that I do not know how to actually traverse the tree and evaluate its expressions. It will be much easier for me to put an example here:

"upper(left("text"),2)" <- this operation is a nested operation which is supposed to: 1. shift "text" by 2 to the left (it does not really matter what it does actually). 2. Return the shifted value "up". 3. Upper expression is supposed to gather whatever the left() produced and do its thing, in that case take shifted "text" to upper case.

This whole "nested expressions" are causing the problem. I have implemented my own visitor class and I have bunch of methods to override, for example expression, substring, shiftright and so on - all taken from the grammar but I have no idea how to use them in the case I am facing, what methods to use so I could actually use the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the fact that you have a lot of almost-identical names such as `shift_left` vs. `shiftLeft` is just begging for bugs to be introduced, so I strongly recommend you refactor your grammar to either:

```
expression : text
           | shiftLeft
           | shiftRight
           | upperCase
           | lowerCase
           | substring
           | concatenate
           ;
text : TEXT;
substring : SUBSTRING OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET;
shiftLeft : SHIFT_LEFT OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET;
shiftRight : SHIFT_RIGHT OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET;
upperCase  : UPPER OBRACKET expression CBRACKET;
lowerCase : LOWER OBRACKET expression CBRACKET;
concatenate : expression CONCANTENATE expression;
```

Or:

```
expression : TEXT #text
           | SHIFT_LEFT OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET #shiftLeft
           | SHIFT_RIGHT OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET #shiftRight
           | UPPER OBRACKET expression CBRACKET #upperCase
           | LOWER OBRACKET expression CBRACKET #lowerCase
           | SUBSTRING OBRACKET expression COMMA NUMBER COMMA NUMBER CBRACKET #substring
           | expression CONCANTENATE expression #concatenate
           ;
```

I'd go with the latter because it produces a simpler tree.

To visit nested expressions, you simply call `Visit` recursively on the subexpressions and then combine the results as appropriate. So a visitor that covers your example could simply look like this:

```
override String VisitText(TextContext ctx) {
    return ctx.TEXT().Text();
}

override String VisitUpper(UpperContext ctx) {
    return Visit(ctx.expression()).ToUpper();
}

override String VisitShiftLeft(ShiftLeftContext ctx) {
    int n = int.Parse(ctx.NUMBER().Text());
    // I'm assuming here that "shift left by N" means "remove N first chars"
    return Visit(ctx.expression()).Substring(n);
}
```

The visit methods for the other expression types would follow the same logic.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've just saved my life. :) Now everything's work like a charm. I used your latter option with grammar and after some tweaks the whole visitor is pretty much done. I'm putting the code down here for anyone who might need it in future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @sepp2k - I'm putting the whole solution in C# of the visitor:

```
public sealed class TreeEvaluationVisitor : TestBaseVisitor<Object> {

   public override object VisitText([NotNull] TestParser.TextContext context) {

        int string_length = context.TEXT().ToString().Length;
        return context.TEXT().ToString().Substring(1, string_length - 2);     
        //Substring() up here is for omitting the quote marks in the final output
    }

    public override object VisitUpperCase([NotNull] TestParser.UpperCaseContext context) {

        int string_length = Visit(context.expression()).ToString().Length;
        return Visit(context.expression()).ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    public override object VisitLowerCase([NotNull] TestParser.LowerCaseContext context) {

        int string_length = Visit(context.expression()).ToString().Length;
        return Visit(context.expression()).ToString().ToLower();
    }

    public override object VisitShiftLeft([NotNull] TestParser.ShiftLeftContext context) {

        int n = int.Parse(context.NUMBER().ToString());
        return sh_left(Visit(context.expression()).ToString(), n);
    }

    public override object VisitShiftRight([NotNull] TestParser.ShiftRightContext context) {

        int n = int.Parse(context.NUMBER().ToString());
        return sh_right(Visit(context.expression()).ToString(), n);
    }

    public override object VisitConcatenate([NotNull] TestParser.ConcatenateContext context) {
        string left = Visit(context.expression(0)).ToString();
        string right = Visit(context.expression(1)).ToString();

        return left + right;
    }

    public override object VisitSubstring([NotNull] TestParser.SubstringContext context) {

        int n1 = int.Parse(context.NUMBER(0).ToString());
        int n2 = int.Parse(context.NUMBER(1).ToString());

        return Visit(context.expression()).ToString().Substring(n1, n2);

    }

    //shift methods for shifting strings, i. e. left("abc",2) -> result = cab
    private static string sh_left(string chain, int amount) {  

        return (chain.Substring(amount) + chain.Substring(0, amount));

    }
    private static string sh_right(string chain, int amount) {

        return chain.Substring(chain.Length - amount) 
               + chain.Substring(0, chain.Length - amount);

    }
```

Comment: You can put `using static TestParser;` at the beginning of the file if you want to get rid of all the `TestParser.`s in the class names.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. Surely, I'll do that. Nevertheless, for academic purpose, you've basically covered the whole problem for me.